# Directory Listener z Commons IO - action can't be completed

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-io

I wrote an application that listens to a given folder, then logs events and writes to the database (action type, file name, content, date).
I based the applications on the Producer Consumer pattern and used the ArrayBlockingQueue.

I have a problem of this type, that when I add a file in this folder and later I want to delete or modify it (this applies only to the first file created in this folder) it pops up

[image: error]

This is one thing, the other one that I would like to skip while (in some way) in DbWriter and I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: link to repo: https://github.com/tomek1221/DirectoryListener

Comment: what do you mean by “skip while (in some way) in DbWriter ”? If the file is in DbWriter, deletion on it should be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not delete the file because in`FileProcessor.getContent`, you create a `FileReader` and did not close it, this will cause the JVM lock the file. To solve this problem, just close the `FileReader` after using, like this :

```
public static String getContent (File file) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    String content = IOUtils.toString(fileReader);
    fileReader.close();
    return content;
}
```